# how to set element center in the div

Tags: javascript

suppose i have text, images etc in div. so how can i make the element center horizontally and vertically in the div with the help javascript & css. please guide with sample code.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do this all with css.

for horizontal center, use the text-align class.

For vertical center, I have used line-height --

this link goes over centering:

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html